# How to prevent screen Recording in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording

Is there any way to disable the screen recording like ZEE5 or Netfix? or is it possible through a configuration profile? or any third-party library is available? My application not using DRM protected video.

I am aware of UIScreen.capturedDidChange observer but it will give info for recording start/stop.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenRecording), name: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange, object: nil)

func preventScreenRecording() -> void {
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    var isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured

     if (isCaptured) {
       self.blockView.hidden = false
     }
     else {
       self.blockView.hidden = true
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most of us observe `UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification`, the contemporary replacement for your snippet’s use of `NSNotification.Name.UIScreenCapturedDidChange`, as well as check `isCaptured` when first presented, to determine whether user is recording or not, and then pause the playback and/or add overlay. I believe that Netflix and others are using a DRM solution that permits the stopping of the recording, a solution that is not available to us.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Disabling the screen recording feature in the app? You can disable the screen recording feature in your app, which prevents the user from capturing the app screen with the native iOS screen recording feature. To disable the screen recording feature in your app, you can add the following code in the ViewController of the screen where you want to disable the recording feat.

Thought:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    @IBAction func presentModalButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
        
        // Set isModalInPresentation to true to prevent screen capture
        modalViewController.isModalInPresentation = true
        
        present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the transition style for the modal view controller
        modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? [isModalInPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-ismodalinpresentation) which says *A Boolean value indicating whether the view controller enforces a modal behavior*

Comment: Thanks  , forgive the English. I'll add what I'm thinking of.

Comment: I tried this code and it doesn't seem to have any impact on screen recording. I can start the recording at any time. Maybe more code is needed?